# Java error java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> when trying to sort list using Collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to return the sorted version of arrnew but it keeps giving me an error on the part Collections.sort(arrnew). My goal of this code is to accept a variable n .I find all factorial numbers of n and find prime factors of those numbers and add it to the array.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class test2 {
    public static List<Integer> factorFactorial(int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrnew = new ArrayList<>();
        while(n>0) {
            int x=n;
            for (int i = 2; i <= x ; i++) {
                while (x % i == 0) {
                    arrnew.add(i);
                    x = x / i;
                }
            }
            n--;
        }
        ;
        return Collections.sort(arrnew);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer>a=factorFactorial(10);
        for(int x:a){
            System.out.print(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Collections.sort() returns void, but you have specified your method should return a list. You can simply change your code to return the sorted list:

```
Collections.sort(arrnew)
return arrnew;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) signature is `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort​(List<T> list)`, so as it is `void` it doesn't return the given list, you have to split it in

```
Collections.sort(arrnew)
return arrnew;
```

---

Or using `Stream` you can inline it and return a new list object

```
return arrnew.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: (1-) The method already creates a new instance of the ArrayList and sorts it. Why would you want to complicate the code by using a stream to sort and then create a second instance of the List?

Comment: @camickr `Collections.sort` _does not_ create a new list; it sorts it in-place. There are cases where this may not be desirable (though even if it were desired to make a copy, it would still be more efficient to copy to a new `ArrayList` and then sort in-place).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, I guess my comment wasn't clear. The method I was referring to was the OPs "factorFactorial" method which 1) creates the ArrayList, 2) populates the data and 3) sorts the data. I was commenting about why you would complicate that method by using a "stream" to sort and create a second List.

Comment: @camickr it was just to present a ont-liner solution

Comment: Never understood why people worry about a one line solution, especially when you add extra overhead. The only issue was the OP didn't understand that the Collections.sort(...) was done in place.